# one button shows shadow and two don’t: I cannot tell why

Tags: android, android-layout, button, android-button

I am dealing with the strangest situation. I have three buttons in a layout file. One of them cast a shadow and two don’t. Even if I add `android:elevation="10dp”` to one of the buttons not casting a shadow, they still don’t. Here is the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_look">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/new_look"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@drawable/sel_ripple"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
        android:text="New look"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/look_btn"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/btn_holder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/16dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="@dimen/8dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_yes"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/32dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/sel_ripple"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
            android:text="@string/yes"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/look_btn"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_no"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/sel_ripple"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
            android:text="@string/no"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/look_btn"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
…
</LinearLayout>
```

`ban_yes` and `ban_np` are the ones not showing a shadow.

Comment: Obviously, the two no-shadow buttons inside a `LinearLayout`, and some attributes inside this make it no-shadow. I guess `android:padding="@dimen/8dp"` eats the two buttons shadow. Anyway I think you should post a image, so other people can see what happen to your buttons.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Actually I added the padding to see if that would help, so it's not the cause. If someone wants to help they can easily paste the code in their android studio. That's why I show the code.

Comment: No really easily, this xml contains too many local variables. You can't confirm other people get the same vision as you see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add layout_marginBottom to your buttons inside the layout. This gives some room for the button to show it's elevation

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_yes"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/32dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/sel_ripple"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
        android:text="@string/yes"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/look_btn"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        />
```

EDIT: The other approach is, on the layout wrapping the button, use

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/btn_holder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/16dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="@dimen/8dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    >
```

This might be a better solution, if you don't need the extra margin.

Comment: That actually worked! thanks. How come the container didn't make room for the shadow? Does this have to do with `GhostView`? Do you mind explaining, if you know?

Comment: Hi @Nouvel Travay, add another solution to it, that might help explain a little more. You provide a good question, so I upvote your question. If you like my answer, you can do so as well :)

Comment: Yep! It's a nicer solution. +1. I still don't understand the underlying reason, though. I wish someone would explain. The source code of the View class is massive. But still I have been looking through it for an explanation. I like to understand things. Not just monkey see monkey do.